# vector<string> and find: template argument deduction/substitution failed?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, iterator

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
vector<string> names;
...

string lh = "localhost";
vector<string>::iterator it = std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), lh);

if(it != names.end())
    names.push_back(lh);
```

The line with `find` results in:

```
../source/ac-pki-4.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > GetServerAltNames()’:
../source/ac-pki-4.cpp:757:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::basic_string<char>&)’
../source/ac-pki-4.cpp:757:76: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_facets.h:50:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_ios.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from /home/jwalton/ac/include/ac-common.h:33,
                 from ../source/ac-pki-4.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:371:5: note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> > >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, const _CharT2&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:371:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../source/ac-pki-4.cpp:757:76: note:   ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >’ is not derived from ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >’
make: *** [source/ac-pki-4.o] Error 1
```

I also tried the following with no joy:

```
std::basic_string<char> lh = "localhost";
```

And I tried a `const_iterator` with no joy.

Below is a screen capture of what I am seeing under Eclipse.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (And why is a `istreambuf_iterator` being used in this case?).

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is a problem somewhere else, since this example works: https://ideone.com/9CV0tC

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Can you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that fails to compile for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<iostream>` seems to be including some headers that have an overload of `std::find` that is different from the one that resides in `<algorithm>`. In order to use the correct one, you must include `<algorithm>`. Uncomment the include line on this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa9eb0d09c0f524f) to see what I mean (and `<iostream>` too for further investigation.) See [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/libstdc++/api/a01725.html) docs.

Comment: Good thinking. The coliru link you posted does include `<algorithm>`

Comment: @Praetorian I'm pretty certain that's the cause of the error. Because I forgot to include it at first.

Comment: I agree. I was suggesting maybe you comment out `#include <algorithm>` in your code to show that it generates a similar error message.

Comment: Yep, that was it... Where did the `istreambuf_iterator` come from?

Comment: @noloader No idea really, but you can browse [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/libstdc++/api/a01725.html) for clues.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's what threw me. The compiler did not complain it could not find `find`. It complained about an `istreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: @noloader Indeed, weird things happen if you don't include the proper headers.